# Java Akka Actors - Message throttling and priority

Tags: java, scala, akka, reactive-programming, actor

Newbie here..

Using akka version: akka-actor_2.11(2.4.8) via the Java API.

I'm trying to develop an actor for generating PDF documents. These PDF documents can be large so obviously I want to throttle the rate in which the actor processes the request. Also as a side requirement, I also need a "prioritizable" inbox by which the PDF generation requests can be processed based on priority by the underlying actors.

In my application startup, I create a global props like this:

```
Props.create(PdfGeneratorActor.class).withDispatcher("prio-dispatcher").withRouter(new RoundRobinPool(1))
```

Then I create actor per pdf request like this:

```
actorSystem.actorOf(propsObjShownAbove, actorType.getCanonicalName() + "_" + UUID.randomUUID());
```

My application.conf looks like this:

```
    prio-dispatcher {
  mailbox-type = "com.x.y.config.PriorityMailbox"
}
```

My PriorityMailbox looks like this:

```
public class PriorityMailbox extends UnboundedPriorityMailbox {
    // needed for reflective instantiation
    public PriorityMailbox(final ActorSystem.Settings settings, final Config config) {
        super(new PriorityGenerator() {
            @Override
            public int gen(final Object message) {
                System.out.println("Here is my message to be prioritized: "+message);
                if (message instanceof Prioritizable) {
                    Prioritizable prioritizable = (Prioritizable) message;
                    if (prioritizable.getReportPriorityType() == ReportPriorityType.HIGH) {
                        return 0;
                    } else if (prioritizable.getReportPriorityType() == ReportPriorityType.LOW) {
                        return 2;
                    } else if (message.equals(PoisonPill.getInstance())) {
                        return 3; // PoisonPill when no other left
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    // Default priority for any other messages.
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is this the right configuration to achieve what I wanted? I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Firstly, I can't see any System.out.prints on my mailbox implementation. I would imagine it should come there to compare the priority.

Secondly, I would expect the PdfGenerationActor to be executing sequentially (one by one) because it is essentially a single instance across the system. But I don't see that happening. I see multiple actors processing the requests concurrently.

I think I'm missing something fundamental here.

Answer (score 0):

I think what happens in your case is that each actor you create has it's own router, but otherwise they are independent - so they execute in parallel.

If you want your requests to be executed sequentially the idea would be to have one router with one "worker"/routee that executes each request one by one. (of course you could configure the number of requests you want to execute in parallel)

So you would have something like this:

in the conf:

```
  mypriority-mailbox {
        mailbox-type = "com.x.y.config.PriorityMailbox"
        mailbox-capacity = 500 #some stuff - you may want to check what you want here - if you want something
        mailbox-push-timeout-time = 100s #some other stuff - check if it makes sense for you
 }

 actor {
     /pdfRouter{
         router = round-robin-pool
         nr-of-instances = 1
         mailbox = mypriority-mailbox
      }
 }
```

in the code:

```
system.actorOf(
            FromConfig.getInstance().props(PdfGeneratorActor.class),
            "pdfRouter");
}
```

check also the documentation for [mailboxes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/java/mailboxes.html) and [routers](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/java/routing.html#simple-router-java)